# Not able to extract correct Value from URL using regular expression in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract value of code from API response Header

This is the URL

```
Location : https://xxxx?code=MDXEVlThajoGXJj_-l6bYFaLxileF49d&state=8edf0d78`
```

I am using this Regular expression

`Location: https://xxxx?code=([^"]+)\s`, but it is returning
`code=MDXEVlThajoGXJj_-l6bYFaLxileF49d&state=8edf0d78` ( whole value along with State) whereas I only want `code=MDXEVlThajoGXJj_-l6bYFaLxileF49d` (State value is not required and  should be truncated)

Let me know what am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude matching a whitespace char or an ampersand, and start the pattern with a word boundary to prevent a partial word match:

```
\bcode=([^\s&]+)&
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFDP62/1).

Or if the ampersand is not mandatory:

```
\bcode=([^\s&]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should go like this

```
code=([^ ]+)&
```

Comment: I think lazy selector `+?` would be even better here.

Answer (score 0):

1. `\s` meta character stands for the whitespace, you need to replace it with an ampersand
2. `?` is a meta character which matches preceding characters zero or one time, you need to escape it

   [image]

or just use something like:

```
code=(.+?)&
```

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Meta characters in regular expressions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearquest/9.0.1?topic=tags-meta-characters-in-regular-expressions)

Also you can consider using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), in this case you need only to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between:

[image]